# Openstack Identity admin client: cannot find users, roles and services

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, keystone, icehouse

I'm using Openstack "ice-house" and the "admin" user. My openstack4j version is 2.0.3.

Using Identity admin client, I can only get **a part of** my tenants-list.

**Even worse**, when I try to list "users", "roles" and "services", it returns an empty list or NULL.

Here is my code sample:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
                .endpoint("http://localhost:5000/v2.0/")
                .credentials("admin", "secret")
                .tenantName("admin")
                .authenticate();

System.out.println(os.identity().tenants().list());  // Get Only A Part of my tenant list
System.out.println(os.identity().users().list());  // Get Empty List
System.out.println(os.identity().services().list());  // Also Get Empty List
```

I tried some solutions on Internet. For example:

```
OSClient os = OSFactory.builder()
                .endpoint("http://localhost:5000/v2.0/")
                .credentials("admin", "secret")
                .tenantName("admin")
                .perspective(Facing.ADMIN)
                .authenticate();
```

and I got connection failed (timeout) error.
Then I tried `.perspective(Facing.PUBLIC)` ,there is no error, however, I still got empty list or NULL.

Anyone could help me about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i solved using : 
OSFactory.enableLegacyEndpointHandling(true);